# Jquery Slide in and slide out box issue

Tags: jquery

long time back i developed one Jquery Slide in and slide out box which was working. when user scroll down and come to end of page then i use jquery animate function to show div with Slide in and slide out effect.

### here is small code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == ($('body').height() - $(window).height()))
        {
            // show container
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'0px','opacity':'1'}, { queue: false, duration: 500, easing: 'easeInCubic' });          
        }
        else
        {
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px','opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500});          
        }
    });

$('#slidebox').bind('click',function()
{

$('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px','opacity':'0'},{queue: false, duration: 500}); 

});

});
```

here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/wjvbK/27/ where code is not working but i could not being able to catch the issue. so looking for suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, just added `jquery-ui.js` in your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjvbK/28/)